# how can I set an inner attribute in an extracted android xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, textview

I have extracted this android xml:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:background="#f9ffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <com.m.view.text.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/userNameLable"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="UserName"
                android:textColor="#516063"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/userNameInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/input_box_idle"
                android:hint="Your Username"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#516063"
                android:textColorHint="#b4c8cf"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

how can i set attributes of the `MyTextView` from the outer xml (that has `include` in it) ?

if I create a java class with getters and setter, the corresponding xml attributes will effect automatically?

Comment: Your question is not clear. How do and which attributes you want to set ?

Answer (score 0):

you can set attributes from java code, like for any other textview

Comment: i want from xml, not from java

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because you import a layout as it is, otherwise implement another specific layout, if you have to change the whole structure of a textview, might as well create another one

Comment: if I create a java class with getters and setter, the corresponding xml attributes will effect automatically?